# Foreground Service Freezing Notification Bar On Pulldown

Tags: java, android, service

I am working on an Android application where I am starting a background service that runs for an indefinite amount of time which works just fine but after doing some research, it seems I should be adding it as a foreground service so that it has a less chance of ever being killed. I also want this service to continue running in the background even if the app closes or is killed. After adding a foreground service to my service class, I have noticed that when you pull down the notification bar the phone freezes and the screen wipes blank for a few seconds before showing back up. The notification bar works as planned after it loads but it is taking way too long. I am fairly new to services but am starting to get a better grasp on them so any help is greatly appreciated. Have been testing this on a One Plus Two phone running Anodrid 5.1.1. Here is my app setup:

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MileageService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction("start");
    startService(serviceIntent);

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

MileageService.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //Everything under here before the final return START_STICKY 
    //was newly added and is the source of the new issues

    if (intent.getAction().equals("start")) {
        if(stringNames.size() == 0) {
            subscribeToLocationUpdates();

            Intent stopIntent = new Intent(this, MileageService.class);
            stopIntent.setAction("stop");
            PendingIntent pStopIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, stopIntent, 0);

            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.icon_name);
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Mileage Service")
                    .setTicker("Mileage Service")
                    .setContentText("Mileage service is running")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.android_logo)
                    .setLargeIcon(icon)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Stop", pStopIntent).build();
            startForeground(101, notification);
        }else{
            return START_STICKY;
        }
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals("stop")) {
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc) {
    Log.i("***********", "Location changed");
    //I also do code here that updates global variables 
    //that get put into an intent to be sent back to app in further 
    //activities but not showing it as it works fine before adding 
    //notification foreground code

    intent.putExtra("names", stringNames);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);        
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your phone, not anything an app could do.

Comment: If I remove the notification piece of code, it runs just fine which makes me think otherwise.  I have been testing and running this on a One Plus Two running Android 5.1.1 just for further information.

Comment: How big are your icons?  Are they appropriately sized by Android standards?

Comment: Yikes I just now notice that the android_logo is 1600 x 1600.  I'm going to replace that and go from there. I was aware of the standards just never checked the default icon set.  Will update with my results.

Comment: Yes, it does cost CPU to decode images to a bitmap...

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much. I will start using my own icons in the future or at least check the sizes.